# Merge jogging with running

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I propose to merge [jogging](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jogging) with [running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running).

Although jogging is mostly talking about running at a slower pace there is no real difference between them. I think making jogging a synonym of running would be good.

Comment: [Does the “running” tag need to be more granular?](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/q/229/3941) was topic before on meta, have not seen it and sure is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about that. Running includes Jogging and Sprinting, you could say Running and Jogging are the same and Running and Sprinting are the same, but Jogging and Sprinting are not the same.

Comment: I think Cycling.SE has separate tags based on how fast you plan to go (there was some discussion on this somewhere sometime), so I think we should probably go with the same. So, have jogging, sprinting and also a "running" tag for the general purpose questions.

Comment: I forgot about [tag:sprinting], all of the running questions I checked were mostly about jogging, but as sprinting is active, I no longer think that a merge is good.